# Shader Modifiers to Extend SceneKit

Tags: glsl, shader, scenekit

Isn't it possible to use functions in my surface.shader.fragment file like this:

```
float time = u_time;

float multiply(float n) {
    return n*2.0;
}; 
vec3 color = vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0);
_surface.diffuse = vec4( color, 1.0 );
```

If I remove the function multiply everything work as expected. There is a custom global function in the code snippet in SCNShadable doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
float multiply(float n) {
    return n*2.0;
}

#pragma body
float time = u_time;
vec3 color = vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0);
_surface.diffuse = vec4( color, 1.0 );
```

The `#pragma body` directive is important here and illustrated in the [documentation for `SCNShadable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadable) as well as the `SCNShadable.h` header file.

You will also want to use the [`.surface`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadermodifierentrypoint/1523791-surface) entry point if you want to change the diffuse colour.

Comment: Hell yeah, thank you! I tried it with #pragma body, but my fault was, that I left the float time = u_time; declaration always on top and not below #pragma body.